# awk using variable

Tags: shell, awk

I am unable to get macthed value although i can see count and pattern value in log.Please help me my requirement is to get list of devices in variable but i think it's not picking up count and pattern value .

```
pattern=ABCD
count=4
x=3
if [[ $count -gt $x ]] ; then
echo "Count : $count" >> ${LOGFILE}
echo "Pattern : $pattern" >> ${LOGFILE}
list=cat /tmp/info.txt | awk 'a-->0;/"$pattern"/{a=$count}'
echo "List : $list" >> ${LOGFILE}`
```

I have tried below way but not working

```
cat /tmp/info.txt | awk 'a-->0;/"$pattern"/{a=$count}' >> ${LOGFILE}
```

When I run directly on commandline it's working fine...

```
cat /tmp/info.txt | awk 'a-->0;/ABCD/{a=4}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"pattern" is a shell variable. awk is not shell, it's awk, therefore you should not expect to access shell variables within awk scripts just like you wouldn't expect to access them within C programs.

See question 24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ:

http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

and use the "-v" option.

Then fix your shell issues too and get this result:

```
pattern=ABCD
count=4
x=3
if [[ $count -gt $x ]] ; then
echo "Count : $count" >> "$LOGFILE"
echo "Pattern : $pattern" >> "$LOGFILE"
list=$(awk -v pattern="$pattern" -v count="$count" 'a-->0; $0 ~ pattern{a=count}' /tmp/info.txt)
echo "List : $list" >> "$LOGFILE"
```

which doesn't make much sense but should be syntactically correct at least once you add the `fi` in the appropriate place. If you tell us what you're trying to do we can help you write a sensible script to do it.